# TypeError: Argument 'payload' has incorrect type (expected bytes, got str). How can I fix it? Why it works on Python 2 but not using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scapy

I am pretty new in Python and I have the following problem using *scapy** library. Here you can find the entire code (but I think that it is not so important because the error is on a specific line: https://github.com/AndreaNobili/replace_download/blob/master/replace_download.py)

Into a **Python 2** project I have the following two lines:

```
modified_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: https://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar590.exe\n\n")

# Replace the original packet payload with the packet forget by scapy:
packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet))
```

This is the code of my **set_load()** function:

```
def set_load(packet, load):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    print("set_load() START")

    # When the victim try to download a ".exe" file he\she is redirected to this other ".exe" link:
    packet[scapy.Raw].load = load
    # The value of the following fields are changed because the file is changed, they will be removed and
    # scapy automatically recalculate the values of these fields inserting the correct values:
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet
```

So basically I am forging a packet using **scapy**, finally I am setting the payload of the original **packet** variable with the payload forged by **Scapy**:

```
packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet))
```

**NOTE:** The **packet variable is not a **scapy** packet but a packet obtained using **netfilterqueue**

Running my script with **Python 2** it works fine but using **Python 3** this last line give me the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument 'payload' has incorrect type (expected bytes, got str)
> /root/Documents/PycharmWS/replace_download/replace_download.py(61)process_packet()
-> packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet))
```

So I am converting the **scapy** packet into a **string** and then I am setting the payload of the original **netfilterqueue** packet but it seems that it is expecting a **bytes**

How can I fix this problem? What am I missing?

Another doubt is: why Python 2 it is working fine? I suspect that the **netfilterqueue** dependency version used by Python 2 is slightly different from the one used by Python 3 and in the old version expected a **string** instead a **bytes** parameter. Is this reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this is because of how unicode strings are handled in Python. Did you have a look at this post and try to convert your string into a byte array: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3050? Also probably worth to have a look at this: http://python3porting.com/problems.html.

Comment: Python 2 was lax about distinguishing between bytes and strings that happened to contain only ASCII characters. Python 3 is not. `bytes` is for binary data, even if it *looks* like a string. `str` is for text, even if it *is* just ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 uses "bytes" on the wire. Instead of using `str()`, use `bytes()`. Have a look at http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#strings-and-bytes for a great comparison of what you should be doing on Py3 vs on Py2.

In your case, just do

```
packet.set_payload(bytes(modified_packet))
```

Comment: There, there. Sorry about that :-)